# QGIS installed plugin not showing in python/plugins folder (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, qgis

I just started using a service called AmigoCloud and they have a plugin for QGIS. However, when I install the plugin it doesn't show on the python/plugins folder. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and QGIS 2.99. When I search for a "python" folder on the computer the only one that contains some plugins for QGIS is the one on the image below.  I'd like to see the code behind the plugin for personal study.

[image: Ubuntu version]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check in this directory

```
/home/user-name/.qgis2/python/plugins
```

Either check the `.qgis2` directory in your system. inside that you will get the installed plugins.